# Nested Callback function with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I want to get a response from callback function async/await style of javascript using kotlin coroutines.

Here is my callback functions

```
offlineCatalog.findOfflineVideoById(id, object : OfflineCallback<Video> {
     override fun onSuccess(video: Video?) {
         video?.let { 
              //Return This Video
         } ?: kotlin.run { 
              findVideoOnline(id, state) 
         }
    }
    override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable?) {
         findVideoOnline(id, state)
    }
})

onlineCatalog.findVideoByID(id, object : VideoListener() {
    override fun onVideo(video: Video?) {
         video?.let { 
             //Return This Video 
         } ?: kotlin.run { 
            Log.e("Return Error") 
         }
    }
    override fun onError(errors: MutableList<CatalogError>) {
         super.onError(errors)
         Log.e("Return Error")
    }
})
```

I want to call function that will return video object from `OfflineCatalog` if error in `OfflineCatalog` then search from `OnlineCatalog`.

such as

```
 try{
     val video:Video? = getVideo(id:String)
     //do something 
 }catch(throwable:Throwable){
     Log.e("Video not found")
 }
```

**Update: My Implementatio**n

this is what I came up with

```
suspend fun getVideo(id: String): Video? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var video = getVideoOffline(id)
    video?.let { video } ?: kotlin.run { getVideoOnline(id) }
}

suspend fun getVideoOffline(id: String): Video? = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    (offlineCatalog.findOfflineVideoById(id, object : OfflineCallback<Video> {
        override fun onSuccess(video: Video?) = cont.resume(video)
        override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable?) = cont.resume(null)
    }))
}

suspend fun getVideoOnline(id: String): Video? = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    catalog.findVideoByID(id, object : VideoListener() {
        override fun onVideo(video: Video?) = cont.resume(video)
        override fun onError(errors: MutableList<CatalogError>) = cont.resume(null)
    })
}
```

Usage-

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    getVideo(id)?.let { 
        //Do Something
    } ?: kotlin.run{
        //Video Not Found
    }
}
```

Comment: you should make `findOfflineVideoById` and `findVideoByID` suspend functions

Comment: but I cannot call findVideoByid inside callback because we have to call resume there

Comment: show these functions

Comment: thses are prebuilt functions from brightcove player.  [Catalog](https://docs.brightcove.com/android-sdk/javadoc/com/brightcove/player/edge/Catalog.html#findVideoByID-java.lang.String-com.brightcove.player.edge.VideoListener-) & [OfflineCatalog](https://docs.brightcove.com/android-sdk/javadoc/com/brightcove/player/edge/AbstractOfflineCatalog.html#findOfflineVideoById-java.lang.String-com.brightcove.player.edge.OfflineCallback-)

Comment: ok, then the `getVideo` function will be a little bit complex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do something like this

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
suspend fun getVideo(id: String): Video? = coroutineScope {
    val offlineVideo: Video? = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        offlineCatalog.findOfflineVideoById(id, object : OfflineCallback<Video> {
            override fun onSuccess(video: Video?) {
                cont.resume(video)
            }
            override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable?) {
                cont.resume(null)
            }
        })
    }
    offlineVideo ?: suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        // offlineVideo not found so search from onlineCatalog
        onlineCatalog.findVideoByID(id, object : VideoListener() {
            override fun onVideo(video: Video?) {
                cont.resume(video)
            }

            override fun onError(errors: MutableList<CatalogError>) {
                super.onError(errors)
                cont.resumeWithException(someException)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

then you can call it as you wanted

```
someScope.launch {
    try {
        val video: Video? = getVideo(id)
        //do something
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.e("Video not found")
    }
}
```

Read more about `suspendCancellableCoroutine` [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/simplifying-apis-with-coroutines-and-flow-a6fb65338765)

Comment: I have done something similar which I added to question. Can you take a look? I am doing this in ViewHolder, so which scope would be good?

Comment: Your implementation is technically the same but these scope functions are unnecessary. `video?.let { video } ?: kotlin.run { getVideoOnline(id) }` should be simply `video ?: getVideoOnline(id)`. In a viewHolder you should use activity/fragment.lifecycleScope i.e. `(itemView.context as AppCompatActivity).lifecycleScope`

Comment: But I am using it in fragment to using activity lifecycle here is good?

Comment: Then use fragment.lifecycleScope. To follow [best practices for coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope), you should inject it like this `class MyRecyclerAdapter(val scope: CoroutineScope)`